# Android: Request focus on view (WebView) added via WindowManager

Tags: android, input, webview, android-softkeyboard, android-windowmanager

I am showing a `webView` as an `alertDialog` from a service when my app is not running on foreground, therefore, My `webView` is attached to the screen via `WindowManager.addView()` method.

The `webView` has an `input` field which I want to be accessible by the user. Unfortunately, when the user clicks on the `input` field, **it is not showing the keyboard for users to allow input**.

My `webView` is inside a `cardView` who's params are as follows:

```
public WindowManager.LayoutParams getParamsForOpenWebView() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
        params.x = left;
        params.y = top;

        return params;
    } else {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


        params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
        params.x = left;
        params.y = 200;

        return params;
    }
}
```

If I connect the phone to my laptop and use the laptop keyboard to add inputs to the input field, it works fine but it's just that the keyboard on the phone does not pop-up.

Also, the input is inside the `webView` therefore I cannot use `View.requestFocus()` to get focus unlike in case of an `EditText`.

I would really appreciate any help regarding how to request focus to the `webView` to allow inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to the question myself after a while.

I tried a lot of combinations of different flags but none worked, unless I tried

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
```

These flags gave the results I wanted and hope it helps someone who goes through the same.